# Why is my Rails Thin webserver throwing a bundler error ? - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundler

Here is my `Gemfile`:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.0'

gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.pre2'

gem 'paperclip', :git => 'git://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip.git'
gem 'mime-types', :require => 'mime/types'

gem 'rails3-generators'

gem 'devise',  '~> 1.1.3'
gem 'devise_invitable', '~> 0.3.4'

gem 'declarative_authorization', :git => 'git://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization.git'

gem 'aasm'
gem 'braintree'
gem 'thumbs_up'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem "friendly_id", "~> 3.2"
gem 'aws-s3'

group :development do
    # Server
    gem 'thin'
    #gem 'rspec-rails', '2.0.1'
    gem 'annotate-models', '1.0.4'
    #gem 'rails-erd'
    gem 'annotate'
    gem 'faker', '0.3.1'
    gem 'ruby_parser'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec', '2.0.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
  #gem 'spork', '0.8.4'
  #gem 'factory_girl_rails', '1.0'
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
$ thin start
>> Using rack adapter
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/bundler-1.0.7/lib/bundler.rb:199: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040766
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require': no such file to load -- rails_admin/application_controller (LoadError)
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `block in require'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:239:in `require'
/myapp/config/initializers/rails_admin.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `block in load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `block in load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:591:in `new_constants_in'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in `load_dependency'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:235:in `load'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:201:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:200:in `block in <class:Engine>'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `block in run_initializers'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
/myapp/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    from <internal:lib/rubygems/custom_require>:29:in `require'
    myapp/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/rack-1.2.2/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
    myapp/config.ru:1:in `new'
    myapp/config.ru:1:in `<main>'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `eval'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:36:in `load'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/rack/adapter/loader.rb:45:in `for'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:169:in `load_adapter'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/controllers/controller.rb:73:in `start'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:185:in `run_command'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/lib/thin/runner.rb:151:in `run!'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/thin-1.2.11/bin/thin:6:in `<top (required)>'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/thin:19:in `load'
    /.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/bin/thin:19:in `<main>'
```

I used to have `rails_admin` installed, but I commented it out and ran `bundle update` and `bundle install`.

Still getting this error though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete config/initializers/rails_admin.rb, relax and float down stream.